# opencart htaccess: How to fix seo keywords in url

Tags: opencart

I have successfully created custom seo url for opencart. But there is a problem.

When I click on products from the main page, it works perfectly fine in displaying what I want:
mywebsite.com/products/classic-print-dress

Then for example I would like to click on category -> dresses, this works fine too:
mywebsite.com/categories/dresses

Here is the problem, when I click category -> Dresses -> Classic Print Dress, I get:
mywebsite.com/categories/dresses/products/classic-print-dress

whereas it should be redirecting to mywebsite.com/products/classic-print-dress

This is wrong and I have no idea why. It seems like it is adding the seo keywords to the url... Where did it go wrong??

Comment: Are you putting single keywords in the fields, or the whole SEO path?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Opencart will add category's seo keywords to the url. Basically, you can't tweak its SEO URLs without additional extension.

And even if you overwrite standard seo_url.php, you also need to provide grateful fallback to standard SEO URL module, so existing extensions could work.

You may want to try this [SEO URL extension](http://www.innofive.com/shop-opencart-extensions/seo-expert-ultimate-urls-solution.html).